# Cannot validate character length when posting

Tags: php

I feel like this is supposed to be pretty easy and straight forward although somehow im getting the logic wrong.

```
function postLengthTitle($post_title_test) {
$result;
$title = strlen($post_title_test);
if (!$title < 40 || !$title > 200) {
$result = true;
} else {
$result = false;
return $result;
}

}

function postLengthContent($content_test) {
$result;
$content = strlen($content_test);
if (!$content < 500 || !$content > 2000) {
$result = true;
} else {
$result = false;
return $result;
}

}

if(postLengthTitle($post_title_test) === false){
header("location: ../content/makeapost.php?".htmlspecialchars($postpage2)."");
exit();
}

if(postLengthContent($content_test) === false){
header("location: ../content/makeapost.php?".htmlspecialchars($postpage3)."");
exit();
}
```

The title works fine although the content does not. Giving 500+ characters still gives me the error. Is this the correct way of validating the character length input?

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean, so you cannot really compare that with a number and expect an useful outcome.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware so just doing if (!$content < 500 || !$content > 2000) should be fine? still gives me the error that content is either too short or too long

Comment: This code is beyond evil. `isset()` do not compare length of string - it simply checks if variable is defined at all (so boolean 1 or 0). Other than that naming convention is horrible. `$title` does not contain title itself but length of title string. Function `postLengthContent` returns boolean value but name sugests that it returns content length.

Comment: There are lots of other things wrong with this code. However, I don't know what the code is really suppose to do, so I cannot correct it.

Comment: Also, you changed the code in your question, which I can understand, but it is difficult to provide an answer to a moving target. Adding things to your question, for instance to explain what it should do, is fine, but changing the code itself basically changes the question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Well the question is if its the correct way of validating character length input? and if its not could you please provide an example or atleast point out whats wrong? besides the isset()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's hard to recode code that makes little sense, but here's my best attempt:

```
function validLengthTitle($title) 
{
    $length = strlen($title);
    return ($length >= 40) && ($length <= 200);
}

function validLengthContent($content) 
{
    $length = strlen($content);
    return ($length >= 500) && ($length <= 2000);
}

if(!validLengthTitle($post_title_test)){
    header("location: ../content/makeapost.php?".htmlspecialchars($postpage2)."");
    exit();
}

if(!validLengthContent($content_test)){
    header("location: ../content/makeapost.php?".htmlspecialchars($postpage3)."");
    exit();
}
```

I cannot, in no way, guarantee that this code does what you want it to do.

If you're going to make more length checks you could create a more general function:

```
function validateLength($text, $minLength, $maxLength) 
{
    $length = strlen($text);
    return ($length >= $minLength) && ($length <= $maxLength);
}
```